# Dynamicaly add and save in localStorage inputs via jQuery or Laravel/PHP

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

I am using laravel, I want to dynamically add fields for product properties. The product is added via submit, so if an error occurs, all additional fields disappear. Also, when editing, I need to display them somehow. What is the best way to save them? Via localStorage or does Laravel/PHP have other methods?

P.S. Here the snippet gives an error for some reason. Possibly due to localStorage.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  if(localStorage.getItem("all")){
      $('#newRow').append(localStorage.getItem("all"));
    }
  $("#addRow").click(function () {
          var html = '';
          html += '<div id="inputFormRow">';
          html += '<div class="input-group mb-3">';
          html += '<input type="text" name="properties[key]" class="form-control m-input" placeholder="Key" autocomplete="off">';
          html += '<input type="text" name="properties[value]" class="form-control m-input ml-3" placeholder="Value" autocomplete="off">';
          html += '<div class="input-group-append ml-3">';
          html += '<button id="removeRow" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>';
          html += '</div>';
          html += '</div>';

          $('#newRow').append(html);

          var allfields = [];
          allfields.push(html);

          localStorage.setItem("all", allfields);
      });

    // remove row
    $('#removeRow').on('click', function () {
        $(this).closest('#inputFormRow').remove();
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-group row">
                  <label for="category_id" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Product properties: </label>
                  <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-lg-12">
                          <div id="inputFormRow">
                              <div class="input-group mb-3">
                                  <input type="text" name="properties[key]" class="form-control m-input" placeholder="Key" autocomplete="off">
                                  <input type="text" name="properties[value]" class="form-control m-input ml-3" placeholder="Value" autocomplete="off">
                                  <div class="input-group-append ml-3">
                                      <button id="removeRow" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                          </div>

                          <div id="newRow"></div>
                          <button id="addRow" type="button" class="btn btn-info">Add</button>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: How your form being submitted? Is it via ajax or on submit reload page?

Comment: Simple submit with page reload. I didn't use Ajax here.

Comment: Ah, thats the reason why you have the problem of disappearing of field after page reload.

Comment: If you want to stay the newly added field after submit, you must use ajax submit to make your life easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible, firstly, you have to use array of array, or it just make more sense.
Your input:

```
<input type="text" name="properties[][key]" class="form-control m-input" placeholder="Key" autocomplete="off">    
<input type="text" name="properties[][value]" class="form-control m-input ml-3" placeholder="Value" autocomplete="off">
```

now you will have array, which contains arrays with two keys, "key" and "value".

So after submit in your controller you can simply store your $request->properties in session **before validation**!

```
$request->session()->flash('properties', $request->properties)
```

or just global helper

```
session()->flash('properties', $request->properties)
```

after flash() method data will be available only next request, after that, they will be automatically deleted
then if you have error, you can do in view something like that:

```
@if(session->has('properties'))
@foreach (session('properties') as $prop)
<input type="text" name="properties[][key]" value="{{$prop['key']}}" class="form-control m-input" placeholder="Key" autocomplete="off">    
<input type="text" name="properties[][value]" value="{{$prop['value']}}" class="form-control m-input ml-3" placeholder="Value" autocomplete="off">
@endforech
@endif
```